# Which Azure Cognitive Search analyzer is equivalent to ES keyword analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

The post title is pretty much what I want to ask:

- Which Azure Cognitive Search analyzer is equivalent to ES **keyword** analyzer

I want to store composite values separated by space that should be always searched together, like:

- Cap TC
- Sis B
- Act A
- Act B
- Act C

Answer (score 0):

Using Java API I could find the same keyword analyzer

```
LexicalAnalyzerName.KEYWORD
```

Then I also found the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#built-in-analyzers